# Quote like "Anyone can endure an insult but it takes a saint to pass through praise unharmed"

Tags: eastern-orthodox, resource-request

I read this quote several times quickly in unrelated places and didn't take down the reference because I assumed it to be popular enough for me to find it easily through google. Now I can't find it. Does anyone know who said this? I believe it was an Orthodox Christian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quote comes from "THE LADDER OF DIVINE ASCENT" by St John Climacus.

http://www.prudencetrue.com/images/TheLadderofDivineAscent.pdf

On page 73

> 12. People of high spirit bear offence nobly and gladly, but only holy people and saints can pass through praise without harm.

Comment: I was so hoping that someone would have the answer.  +1 and thank you.